# Is there a weak set theory that can prove that the natural numbers is a model of PA?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, peano-axioms, meta-math, reverse-math

$ZFC$ proves that $\mathbb N$ is a model of $PA$. Even $ZF$ does. How weak can go?

In particular, is there some weak set theory that proves that $\mathbb N$ is a model of $PA$, but does *not* proof that $PA + Con(PA)$ is consistient?

EDIT: The theory should prove that $\mathbb N$ (along with its operations) actually exist.

Comment: Remove the axiom of infinity. That should work.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think you can even proof that $\matbb N$ exists then, right? Since $\mathbb N$ is usually defined as being an inductive set in set theory.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: $\mathsf{ZF}-$Infinity does not work, because adding the *negation* of the axiom of infinity to this theory results in a theory equiconsistent to $\mathsf{PA}$. In fact, the two theories are mutually interpretable and, if appropriately formulated, even bi-interpretable.

Comment: @Andrés: Well, ZF-Infinity *should* work. It does not prove there is a model of PA; but it would prove that the natural numbers *are* a model of PA. And in the case of Infinity failing, I think it is still enough to prove that each of the axioms of PA hold in the natural numbers (which is the class of ordinals, then), as a schema-proof. No?

Comment: @Asaf Only in the same sense that $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves that $V$ is a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was more looking for a single statement proving the result, not a schema. Also, the system should prove that $\mathbb N$ *is* a model of $PA$ (and therefore exists), not that $\mathbb N$ is a model of $PA$ *assuming it exists*.

Comment: So you want a system which can prove that PA has a model, but not the completeness theorem for FOL for countable languages. Sounds incredibly weak, to the point where you seem to want to hold the stick from both ends.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you mean? The completeness theorem just says that a consistient theory has a model, right? So it would prove that $\mathbb N$ is a model of PA, but that $PA + Con(PA)$ has no model, right?

Comment: Yeah, I was taught the completeness theorem as enveloping the soundness theorem. So a theory with a model is consistent. In short, you want a set theory whose natural numbers are a model of PA + ~Con(PA). Or else you want a set theory which does not prove that logic is sound. Again, you seem to want to hold a very long stick from both ends.

Comment: @AsafKaragila the first one sounds more like it.

Comment: But the first one would imply the second one. No? You would have a theory which has a model but isn't "consistent", therefore PA is a theory which is *not* consistent, yet has a model.

Comment: @AsafKaragila ah, I think I see the problem. It is consistent with the theory that PA+not Con(PA) has N as a model, in which case there is a proof of 0=1 from PA in standard length. I could see how that would be a problem.

Comment: In that case, I guess the answer to the second question is no (without breaking things).

Comment: The axiom of replacement is not needed to prove the consistency of $PA$, so the $F$ in $ZF$ is not relevant here. Adrian Mathias's paper [Slim Models of Zermelo Set Theory](https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~ardm/) may be of interest.